# Further customise safeAreaView

Tags: ios, react-native

is it possible to change the color of the bottom bar?

[image: From gray to white]

I would like to color it white. Do you have any ideas?

Goal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
<Fragment>
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          accessibilityLabel="React logo"
          source={{ uri: logoUri }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        This is an example of an app built with{" "}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>To get started, edit .</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Example button" />
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
</Fragment>
```

Can You try this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution colors the whole thing. I added a new picture, to clarify my goal.